# Why does $\sum^{n-1}_{j=i+1}j=\frac{(n+i)(n-i-1)}{2}$

Tags: calculus, summation

Why does $\sum^{n-1}_{j=i+1}j=\frac{(n+i)(n-i-1)}{2}$?

We know that $\sum^{n}_{j=1}j=\frac{(n+1)(n)}{2}$, but how does this standard one transform to the above result. Could someone help?

Comment: The first and last term sum to $n+i$, the second and second-to-last term sum to $n+i$, and so on. There are $\frac{n-i-1}{2}$ pairs of terms each with sum $n+i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j - \sum_{j=0}^{i}j $$
So you have:
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{i(i+1)}{2} $$ which give you a result

Answer (score 2):

That is the sum of an arithmetic progression, which is equal to:

Number of terms $\quad  \times \quad $ Average value

Number of terms = $(n-1-i)$

Average value = $\frac{first+last}{2} = \frac{(i+1)+(n-1)}{2} =\frac{n+i}{2}$